# Find a complex number that is a cube root of something and a forth root of something

Tags: complex-numbers

Find a complex number $z$ that is a cube root of $\ -8i$ and a forth root of$\ -8- 8i\sqrt[]{3} $

Until now:
Thought of a correlation with the number j=$\ \frac{-1}2 +\frac{\sqrt[]{3}}2$

Because $\ j^3=1 $ and $\ j^2= \frac{-1}2 -\frac{\sqrt[]{3}}2 $ but is just an intuition.

Afterwards I have doubts with what the question mean by "z is a cube root of -8i":

Is it like this? : $\ \sqrt[3]{z}=-i8$  or $\ z=\sqrt[3]{-i8}$

Finally I just tried to find the module and the argument of the both complex numbers:

With $\ -8i$ :

module = 8

$\ 8\sin(x)=-8$ -> $\sin(x)=-1 $

argument = $\ -\frac{\pi}2 $

With $\ -8 -8i\sqrt[]{3} $ :

module = $\ 8\sqrt[]{6} $

$\ 8\sqrt[]{6} \cos(x)=-8$ -> $\cos(x)= -\frac{\sqrt[]{6}}6  $

$\ 8\sqrt[]{6} \sin(x)=-8i\sqrt[]{3}$ -> $\cos(x)= -\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}2  $

argument = ??? cant be?

Comment: That is not really a question, it is a problem for others to do. Do you have a question about this problem? What have you tried, so people know how much you know?

Comment: Hint: If $z^3=a$ and $z^4=b$, how do you find $z$?

Comment: Please say what you have tried. Just uploading a problem is not the right way.

Comment: @paul there it is sorry, I just thought what I've done wasn't interesting

Comment: This may be reopened as the OP has shown some effort. Voted accordingly. Also, to @StrugglerMadScientist , Stinking Bishop's comment practically gives you the answer. Another big hint: divide!

Comment: @Deepak, ahhh was actually easy: $$
\frac{z^4}{z^3}=z
$$

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @StinkingBishop's comment:

$\frac{z^4}{z^3} = z = \frac{-8-8i\sqrt[]{3}}{-8i} = \frac{1}{i}+\sqrt[]{3}= \sqrt[]{3}-i.$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Part of what was making things difficult for your approach is that your value for one of the moduli is not correct:

For $ \ z^3 \ = \ -8i \ \ , \ $ the modulus *is* $ \ \sqrt{0^2 + (-8)^2} \ = \ 8 \ \ , \ $ but for $ \   z^4 \ = \ -8 - i·8\sqrt3 \ \ , \ $ it's $ \ \sqrt{(-8)^2 + (-8·\sqrt3)^2} \ = \ \sqrt{64 + 64·3} \ = \ \sqrt{256} \ = \ 16 \ \ . \ $  So if the unknown $ \ z \ = \ \rho \ · \ cis \ \theta \ \ , \ $ we can say that $ \ \rho^3 \ = \ 8 \ $ and $ \ \rho^4 \ = \ 16 \ \ . \ $

So the argument for $ \ z^3 \ $ *is* $ \ -\frac{\pi}{2} \ = \ \frac{3\pi}{2} \ \ , \ $ but the argument of $ \ z^4 \ $ is given by $ \ cis \ \theta \ = \ \frac{-8 \ - \ i·8\sqrt3}{16} \ = \ -\frac12 - i·\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ \ $ (putting this in the third quadrant), so $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{4 \pi}{3} \ \ . \ $

If we take $ \ z \ = \ 2 \ · \ cis \ \theta \ \ , \ $ we now have $ \ z^3 \ = \ 2^3 \ · \ cis(3 \theta) \ \Rightarrow \ 3 \theta \ = \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} + 2m \pi \ $ and $ \ z^3 \ = \ 2^4 \ · \ cis(4 \theta) \ \Rightarrow \ 4 \theta \ = \ \frac{4 \pi}{3} + 2n \pi \ $ ; we have "multiple-angle" trigonometric equations, so we need to allow more than one "cycle" around the origin.  These angle equations give us
$$ \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ + \ m·\frac{2 \pi}{3} \ \ = \ \ \frac{3\pi}{6} \ + \ m·\frac{4 \pi}{6} \ \ \ , \ \ \ \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ + \ n·\frac{2 \pi}{4} \ \ = \ \ \frac{2\pi}{6} \ + \ n·\frac{3 \pi}{6} $$

We could solve this system of equations directly, but it's at least as fast just to start listing values:

first equation -- $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{3\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \frac{7\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \mathbf{\frac{11\pi}{6} } \ \ , \ \ \frac{15\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \ldots $

second equation -- $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{2\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \frac{5\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \frac{8\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \mathbf{\frac{11\pi}{6} } \ \ , \ \ \frac{14\pi}{6} \ \ , \ \ \ldots $

So we find that $$ \ z \ = \ 2 \ · \ cis\left(\frac{11\pi}{6} \right) \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \left(   \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ - \ i·\frac12   \right) \ \ = \ \  \sqrt3 \ - \ i·1 \ \ .  $$

[Of course, we could also just divide or even "eyeball" a factorization:
$$ z^4 \ \ = \ \ -8 \ - \ i·8·\sqrt3 \ \ = \ \ -i·(-8i) \ + \ (-8i)·\sqrt3 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \underbrace{(-8i)}_{z^3} \ · \ \underbrace{(\sqrt3 \ - \ i)}_{z} \ \ . \ ] $$